# iTextSharp Licensing

Tags: itext, licensing

We would like to use iTextSharp DLL in one of our project to extract PDF text but I'm having 2nd thought to release it to production because I read somewhere that we need to purchase a commercial license for us to be able to use iTexttSharp. Is this true?  We will just consumed the DLL and we will not change anything, do we still need to buy a license?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: nope.. Its free.. You can also see its code on github. Here is the License : https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/blob/master/LICENSE.md

Comment: We're using 5.5.6 version and I'm confuse what is mentioned in their [FAQ](http://itextpdf.com/salesfaq)

Comment: Its 5.5.7 but I guess License would not been changed from last May 6, 2015...

Comment: @sac It's only free if you also publish your code under the AGPL (and under the AGPL only). See http://www.slideshare.net/iTextPDF/ianal-what-developers-should-know-about-ip-and-legal

Comment: Do you even use it for ["for non-production servers (e.g. testing, development, Q&A, UAT, BA or DR)"](http://itextpdf.com/Pricing/unit-based) -- if so, whether or not you are currently profiting from it or not, if that describes your use case (according to their own words), you technically need to buy .. at least .. that kind of license.

Answer (score 13):

iText is free software released under the AGPL. This means that it can be used for free *on condition* that you also release the source code of your project for free under the same license. As soon as you start offering the code or the project (e.g. in the context of a SaaS offering) under a different license, then you should purchase a commercial license. That is explained in a [one-minute video](https://youtu.be/QHF3xcWnSD4) and it's the subject of my JavaOne talk on October 28th: [IANAL: what developers should know about IP and legal](http://www.slideshare.net/iTextPDF/ianal-what-developers-should-know-about-ip-and-legal). You'll notice that we have successfully went to court to make sure that the open source license was honored.

Comment: almost correct - if you use version 4.1.6 and below, it uses licence MPL/LGPL and can be used for free / for any purpose without the ristriction to release source code

Comment: @fubo Nope, see https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/versions-older-than-5 If you'd do a thorough due diligence on version 4.1.6, you'd discover that it doesn't stand the test and that it never should have been released as MPL/LGPL.