# Cold Fusion QR Image - JAVA Path

Tags: java, coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

I'm not best with JAVA

I started here with the QRToad
https://github.com/boltz/QRToad

ColdFusion 2016 - MS Server 2016 : I have restarted cf server a few times.

I get an error on line 5

> Class not found: com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BarcodeQRCode

The error occurred in

```
C:/upcloud/_live_websites/_silkea/test/QR/com/timcunningham/QRToad/QRCode.cfc: line 5
Called from C:/upcloud/_live_websites/_silkea/test/qr/getqrtest.cfm: line 2
Called from C:/upcloud/_live_websites/_silkea/test/QR/com/timcunningham/QRToad/QRCode.cfc: line 5
Called from C:/upcloud/_live_websites/_silkea/test/qr/getqrtest.cfm: line 2

3 :                     put the itext JAR in your ColdFusion class path. 
4 :                     Restart ColdFusion service">
5 : <cfset QR = createObject("java","com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BarcodeQRCode")>
```

This is the JAR : itext-pdfa-5.5.13.2.jar

I have put it in: C:\ColdFusion2016\jre\lib
and also C:\ColdFusion2016\cfusion\lib

Am I putting it in wrong spot? Or do I need to change this?

"java","com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BarcodeQRCode"

Comment: For anyone using iText 5, do read the new AGPL license terms https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33164099/itextsharp-licensing

Answer (score 1):

I use this function in combination with [zxing](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.zxing) which is used by the Google QR code applications (including `chart.apis.google.com`). You'll need to download `core-3.4.0.jar` and `javase-3.4.0.jar` and put them in `C:\ColdFusion2016\cfusion\lib`

```
<cfscript>
  public string function createQRCode( 
    required string data,
    integer width=180,
    integer height=180,
    integer margin=4,
  ){
    local.filePath = getTempDirectory() & application.fwUtilService.generateUUID() & '.png';
    local.objQRCodeWriter = CreateObject('java', 'com.google.zxing.qrcode.QRCodeWriter');
    local.objBarcodeFormat = CreateObject('java', 'com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat');
    local.objEncodeHintType = CreateObject('java', 'com.google.zxing.EncodeHintType');
    local.objHashMap = CreateObject('java', 'java.util.HashMap');
    local.objFileSystems = CreateObject('java', 'java.nio.file.FileSystems');
    local.objMatrixToImageWriter = CreateObject('java', 'com.google.zxing.client.j2se.MatrixToImageWriter');
    local.qrCodeWriter = local.objQRCodeWriter.init();
    local.objHashMap.put(local.objEncodeHintType.MARGIN, javacast('int', arguments.margin));
    local.objHashMap.put(local.objEncodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET, "UTF-8");
    local.objEnumMap = CreateObject('java', 'java.util.EnumMap').init(local.objHashMap);
    local.bitMatrix = local.qrCodeWriter.encode(data, local.objBarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, arguments.width, arguments.height, local.objEnumMap);
    local.path = local.objFileSystems.getDefault().getPath(local.filePath, []);
    local.objMatrixToImageWriter.writeToPath(local.bitMatrix, "PNG", local.path);
    return local.filePath;
  }
</cfscript>
```

Comment: Yep. Even easier, load the jars via `this.javaSettings` of your Application.cfc.

Answer (score 0):

This might just be way simpler.

```
      <cfhttp url="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=250x250&cht=qr&chl=http://www.website.com" result="qrcode" getasbinary="yes">
      <cfimage action="writeToBrowser" source="#qrcode.filecontent#" style="height:250px;width:250px">
```

So I'll play with this for a bit, and just try saving the Google Pull.
Other QR Code is quite old.

Yep way simpler. Sniff if qrimg is done, if not create it.

```
      <cfif qrimg is "">


      <cfhttp url="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=250x250&cht=qr&chl=http://webaddress?vid=#vid#&src=p" result="qrcode" getasbinary="yes">

      <cfimage action="writeToBrowser" source="#qrcode.filecontent#" style="height:250px;width:250px">

      <cfimage action="write" source="#qrcode.filecontent#" destination="#expandPath( 'QR_#vid#.jpg' )#" overwrite="true">

      #vnumber# : #vname#<br>

            <cfquery name="nm" datasource="#fds#">
              update fv
              set qrimg = 'QR_#vid#.jpg'
              where vid = '#vid#'
            </cfquery>

      <cfelse>
      <img src="QR_#vid#.jpg">
      <br>
      #vnumber# : #vname#<br>
      </cfif>
```

Comment: Is there a way to also activate camera for QR code scan. From webpage. To avoid navigation clicks. They just scan from within page they are on?